# Is it necessary to check already running service list before starting or stoping a service?

Tags: android, service

while going through a code I found that before starting or stopping a service
a check was placed to confirm whether the service is already running or already stopped.

This was done using Activity Manager which gives information
about already running services in the System.

I want to know is this check necessary ?

1. what would happen if I call startService() for an already running service ?
2. What would happen if I call stopService() for an already stopped service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the Android docs

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though
>   they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()),
>   so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped
>   once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called; however, services
>   can use their stopSelf(int) method to ensure the service is not
>   stopped until started intents have been processed.

So on your question

```
what would happen if I call startService() for an already running service ?
```

**The `onStartCommand()` is called again and again but service once started cannot be started again or nested**

> What would happen if I call stopService() for an already stopped
>   service ?

**When you call it first the `onDestroy()` method is called and later calls are ignored as service doesnt exist any more**

Answer (score 1):

If the service running, it does not create another instance, but onStartCommand() is still called on the existing instance.
You may look into [Service Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) for more details.

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though
>   they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()),
>   so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped
>   once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called; however, services
>   can use their stopSelf(int) method to ensure the service is not
>   stopped until started intents have been processed.

As for stopService, it wont affect anything even if the service in question is not running in my knowledge.

Comment: Service users in general don't need to check if the service is running or not, but it really depends on how the service is implemented. One of the most important parts of a service is handling multiple requests (multithreading), so maybe that service wasn't thought with that in mind as it's not a mandatory requirement for a service.

Answer (score 1):

A service will only run once, no matter how many times you call `startService()`.

Calling `stopService()` will make no effect on an already stopped service.Its like calling `onDestroy()` on a already destroyed Activity.